# Como alinhar radio button e label, com Bootstrap 3.x?

Tags: bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Como alinhar o *radio button* com o *label*, usando o *Bootstrap 3.x*?
Tentei de várias maneiras, porém o "desalinhamento" permanece.

```css
radio{
width:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8 text-info">
 <h4>1. Comprometimento</h4>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-4 text-info">
  <h4>AVALIAÇÃO</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
  <p>Conhece e cumpre as normas estabelecidas na empresa</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline control-label"> 
    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="comprom_perg_a" value="7"> 07 </label>
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline control-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-control"  name="comprom_perg_a" value="8"> 08 </label>
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline"> 
    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="comprom_perg_a" value="9"> 09 </label>
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline"> 
    <input type="radio" class="form-control"  name="comprom_perg_a" value="10"> 10 </label>
 </div>
```

Obs: foi preciso colocar o *style*, porque o *radio button* estava exageradamente grande.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se com "desalinhamento" você quer dizer que os elementos **não ficam na mesma linha** que o *label*, então o que vc procura é a classe *[radio-inline](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#inline-checkboxes-and-radios)* do *Bootstrap v. 3.3.x*.

> Use the .checkbox-inline or .radio-inline classes on a series of checkboxes or radios for controls that appear on the same line.

Ou seja, quando você quiser que eles apareçam na mesma linha, deve aplicar essa classe. Mas entenda uma coisa: a classe controla o elemento *radio* que está dentro dela, assim, o estilo do *input radio* já está definido, e você não pode aplicar outra classe a ele (você está tentando aplicar *form-control*).

Se você for olhar o conteúdo de `bootstrap.css` vai ver isso:

```
.radio-inline input[type=radio]{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:4px\9;
    margin-left:-20px
}
```

Sendo assim, use a classe principal *radio-inline* sem chamar *form-control*:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="text-info"><h4>1. Comprometimento</h4></div>
 <div class="text-info"><h4>AVALIAÇÃO</h4></div>
 <p>Conhece e cumpre as normas estabelecidas na empresa</p>
  
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline control-label"> 
    <input type="radio" name="comprom_perg_a" value="7"> 07 </label>
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline control-label">
    <input type="radio"  name="comprom_perg_a" value="8"> 08 </label>
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline"> 
    <input type="radio" name="comprom_perg_a" value="9"> 09 </label>
  <label for="comprom_perg_a" class="radio-inline"> 
    <input type="radio"  name="comprom_perg_a" value="10"> 10 </label>
 </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para editar qualquer coisa em bootstrap eu costumo criar um arquivo externo de css e declarar ele depois do `bootstrap.min.css`, ficaria algo tipo:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/style.css">
</head>
```

A partir daí é só editar em css as alterações.